# what is "/sbin/init maybe-ubiquity" doing in Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS?

Tags: ubuntu, init, inotify

I have a current problem with a server that goes incommunicado (or at least close to) due to lack of inotify watchers. When I look up the current usage i see that `/sbin/init maybe-ubiquity` is the culprit with 8153 watchers (at boot that count is 570). I have a server installation, i.e., one with no graphical interface and it is currently serving as node in a Galera cluster. All nodes display the same odd behaviour.

What is that process really doing? Is there a way to get rid of it? I could raise the max number of inotify watchers but that would be just fixing the symptom, not the problem...

Comment: Try Ask Ubuntu https://askubuntu.com/questions/1165399/why-maybe-ubiquity-on-default-kernel-command-line